# C++11 : Using local static variables in multithreaded program caused coredump

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-variables

In C++11, I create 100 threads, every thread call Test::PushFunc, add local static variable ***index***, insert to a local set variable ***localMap***.

In theory, ***index*** is stored in **Initialized Data Segment Memory** and was added by every thread in program running time.
Following line

```
assert(it == localMap.end());
```

is reasonable because of ***index*** to be inserted into ***localMap*** is never repeated.

But in practice, program is coredump in assert randomly. Can U tell me why ? Thanks.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
class Test {
public:
    std::set<std::string> localMap;
    void PushFunc()
    {
        static uint64_t index = 0;
        while (true) {
            std::cout << "index : " << index << "\n";
            ++index;
            const auto& s = std::to_string(index);
            const auto& it = localMap.find(s);
            assert(it == localMap.end()); //! coredump here
            localMap.insert(s);
            if (index > 20000000) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};


int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> processThreads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        processThreads.emplace_back(
                std::thread([]()
                {
                    Test t;
                    t.PushFunc();
                }
                ));
    }
    for(auto& thread : processThreads){
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `const auto&`?

Comment: @ÖöTiib `localMap` is not shared between threads, only `index` is.

Comment: Why cannot `const auto&`?  Every variable will not be change can be defined as `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in practice, program is coredump in assert randomly. Can U tell me why ?

Because you have a data race -- multiple threads are trying to read and write the same variable without any synchronization.

The `index` is a *global* variable. You need to guard access to it with a mutex.

**Udate:**

> But localMap is not a global variable, data race cannot explain one index repeated twice.

1. A program with a data race (undefined behavior) can produce *any* result.
2. Yes, it can.

Consider the following instruction interleaving (time goes downwards):

- T1 loads `index` into register (say `5`).
- T2 loads `index` (`5` again)
- T1 increments `index` to `6`, stores `"6"` into its map
- T1 loads `6`, increments `index` to `7`, stores `"7"` into its map
- T2 "increments" index to `6`, stores `"6"` into its own map
- T1 loads `6`, increments it to `7`, tries to store `"7"` into its map ==> assertion failure!

The issue is that `index++` is not an *atomic* operation, and (without mutex) other threads may interfere with it.

Comment: But `localMap` is not a global variable, data race cannot explain one `index` repeated twice.

Comment: @ArmStrong You are mistaken. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @ArmStrong You're updating `index` in multiple threads via `++index`. Same value can be observed by a single thread multiple times(at most 2500).

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thank you very much. Your explanation is very clear.

Comment: What happens if static index was a static std::mutex?
Different threads are referring to to it.
is it thread safe because it is a std::mutex?

Comment: @SJHowe Yes: `mutex` is _specifically_ written to allow safe access from multiple threads (by using platform-specific atomic operations in its implementation).